# InnerHTML with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to run php function inside javascript and pass a parameter to that function but with no luck.

here's my code:

```
var attribute = 1;
var element = getElementByID('wrapper').innerHTML="<?php echo myfunction("+attribute+");?>";
```

But the result I'm getting is the output of my function with "+attribute+" added to it, not the proper output of the function.

The function itself is an easy one:

```
<?php myfunction($attribute){
    echo 7+$attribute;
}?>
```

Comment: PHP is processed in the server and then Javascript is processed in the client's machine.  So, when PHP the to echo the `attribute` variable it doesn't exists yet.

Comment: it's very helpful to read js and php docs, before you start to write any scripts....

Comment: To do something like you are trying to do, call a PHP function from Javascript, to need to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php would be executed by the server, but the server isn't involved anymore once your client has started processing javascript. So no, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: It is possible using Ajax